# Wordpress Ajax request using vue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

I am having issues trying to get data from an ajax call in wordpress.

Here is my code.

PHP

```
<?php 
function pfw_get_websites(){
   $result[] = array(
    "id" => '1',
    "title" => 'this is title',
    "description" => 'this is the description'
  );
    echo json_encode($result);
}?>
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="website in websites">
           {{ website }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

VueJS and AJAX Call:

```
        const app = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            websites: []
        },
        created(){
            var request = {
                action:  "pfw_get_websites"
            };
            $.post(user_obj.ajax_url, request).always(function(response){
                console.log("This is inside vue"  +response);
                console.log("This is inside vue"  +response.title);

                app.websites = response;
            });
        }
    })
```

I can verify that json is returned and I can see values I set in PHP.  However, the page seems to be outputting a list item for each character and letter in the returned json string.

The output on the page is showing each list item only having one character in the json string.  Response.title is coming as undefined.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string returned by PHP to JSON.

Add the following line

```
$.post(user_obj.ajax_url, request).always(function(response){
   response = JSON.parse(response); // Add this line
   console.log("This is inside vue"  +response[0]);
   console.log("This is inside vue"  +response[0].title);
   app.websites = response;
});
```